# Filter JSON from ASP.Net handler | Using Dojo 1.8

Tags: ajax, json, handler, dojo

Wanted to filter the results using Dojo 1.8 based upon the data received from server through a ASP.Net handler.

Handler Example - `http://localhost/net/get8.ashx?longitude=-70.255325&latitude=43.661472&searchradius=200&searchunit=mi&locationtypes=3&numresults=20&Json=y`

I could use (Store API) `ItemFileReadStore` but it's required specific format which we don't have and can't make the changes from the server end (JSON structure changes)

Able to successfully fetch the data through Dojo AJAX but looking for better way to filter the through some Dojo API.

One way around is, restructure the data again on client but it costs the performance and considering we developing for Mobile, doesn't look the right approach to take.

What all other options do we have in Dojo?

P.S. I just started learning Dojo Toolkit but having good experience in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemFileReadStore` has been replaced with the `dojo/Store`.  You should be able to put the data into a `dojo/store/Memory` as is and query from that store.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Memory.html#dojo-store-memory

Answer (score 0):

I already did use Object Store (Memory) to resolve the issue.